# Is it safe to connect house wiring with duct tape?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, code-compliance, safety, fire-hazard

I rent a house in LA that has been given the landlord special--after looking a the wiring to see if I would be able to install a pendant light, I was shocked to find a live wire wrapped with old, crusted duct tape barely attached to a new wire attachment (not the copper grounding wire) as well as another wire with exposed paper. Is this a fire hazard? What do you guys think?

[image: here is the wire without the cap (just came off with barely any effort]

[image: the cap that the live wire was in. Is the duct tape up to code? What about the paper?]

Comment: All the wires except for the white tape/thin black coating wire look fine to me. The paper is included inside multi-wire cable to keep the wires separate/not sticking to each other. Can you post clearer pictures of where that problematic wire starts and ends and zoom in on its coating?

Comment: Interesting! Since you are renting in many areas you are not allowed to open or work on any of the electrical systems. Best check with the landlord and your city.

Comment: *"I rent ... I would be able to install a pendant light"* **No, you can't, as a renter.** Nor can your landlord. A licensed electrician is required.

Comment: you could use a plug in pendant and a socket to plug adapter; all external modifications consumers can make.

Comment: Better make sure your renters insurance is up to date, especially the liability aspect.